# I'm getting a 'couldnt save entry' error for a single but all required fields etc are filled

Tags: error, saving

I'm getting a couldnt save entry error, but all the fields are filled and there are no additional errors or input highlighting. Has anyone has this problem? Tried clearing the cache and checking the logs but nothing, I was able to fill it in fine before but no longer.

This is a screen shot of the error.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed?

Comment: @mmikkel Yep I have amnav installed, I'll try disabling it and seeing if it makes a difference. edit - tried and it didnt help.

Comment: Also, which Edition is this? Craft Personal is limited to 5 Singles.

Comment: @mmikkel it's craft pro, I have a lot of singles, structures and channels already and I've been able to edit it before. Kinda feels like this one is some how 'stuck'. I think I will probably have to re add the section. No sure how to find out anymore info about the problem since it doesnt seem to be giving any additional error information.

Comment: Can't think of anything, but more than happy to have a look if you could create a support ticket from the dashboard (including database of course). Maybe it's something specific to this site that's not easy to reproduce.

Comment: @jackpopp Yeah I'm drawing a blank :/

Comment: @mmikkel no worries, thanks though!

Comment: Validation errors will get logged to your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` files, which is what this probably is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under your single's section settings, you had an invalid URI format for the `cy_gb (Welsh)` locale: `ein heiddo`.

URI's can't have spaces in them.  It'd be nice if Craft could warn you that the URI format is invalid (no spaces, all URL safe characters, etc), but it's difficult because Twig code is allowed in those fields and all sorts of characters that aren't URL safe are allowed in Twig markup.

Comment: Oh man totally missed that, don't know how I ended up doing that. It'll all good now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if [Dev Mode](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/dev-mode) is just for front end problem solving but if not then might be worth a shot trying to enable that and see if it comes up with anything more descriptive then.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, devMode didnt give any extra info unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry that didn't help at all and sorry I didn't add this as a comment as for some reason I didn't have that option when I went to post here.